# integrate AngularJS 2 cli with ASP.NET Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, command-line-interface

I try to create ***Asp.Net Core*** application with ***AngularJS 2***. After final version AngularJS has new ***cli*** features. For example

```
ng generate component person
```

command create new component by given entity name. I try many examples from web github etc. But can't find combined application twice. For example when I try to create new component, retruned result is

```
You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the generate command.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure after you generate the project you then have to "cd" into the project where you cli dependancy modules live to utilise them.